# Which URLs are being used by Firebase on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-crash-reporting

There must be an obvious answer to this that I'm overlooking, but my Google skills are lacking right now.

We need to supply a list of URLs our app is using to a customer, so they can whitelist those URLs with their IT. Our own endpoints are no-brainers, of course, but I don't know about Firebase. Is there anything we need to consider for push notifications? And which URLs are being used for Analytics and Crashlytics?

Thanks!

Comment: The IPs and endpoints that Firebase can use are subject to change over time.  It's not even just URLs - sometimes there are direct sockets that don't have a "URL".

Comment: @DougStevenson That's good to know, and I believe Bruce Lee's answer below helps with the FCM side of things. How can I make sure crash logs and analytics are still being sent, though?